# How to install PL/R on Mountain Lion? make searching wrong path?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.6, command-line-tool, plr

I'm trying to install PL/R on Mountain Lion 10.8.2, I've installed R 2.15.3 from r-project and PostgreSQL 9.1 from KyngChaos. I've got PL/R 8.3.0.14 from http://www.joeconway.com/plr/. I've put the expanded folder in /usr/local/pgsql/share/contrib and cd'd into that folder.

The environment variables $R_HOME and $CUSTOM_COPT are set as instructed at http://www.joeconway.com/web/guest/pl/r/-/wiki/Main/Installation_Mac by writing them into .bash_profile, and also added /library/frameworks/r.framework/resources/bin to my path by writing to the same file.

XCode 4.6 and the Command Line Tools are installed. There are multiple copies of standard C header files, including stdio.h, for example there is /usr/include/stdio.h.

Next step seems to be:

```
DiMac:plr duncan$ make    
Makefile:40: ../../src/Makefile.global: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /contrib/contrib-global.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/contrib/contrib-global.mk'.  Stop.
```

That didn't work, and then I try:

```
DiMac:plr duncan$ make USE_PGXS=1
gcc -Os -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -arch x86_64  -I"." -I"-I/library/frameworks/r.framework/resources/include" -I/library/frameworks/r.framework/resources/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/include/internal -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DPKGLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/lib\" -DDLSUFFIX=\".so\" -DR_HOME_DEFAULT=\"/library/frameworks/r.framework/resources\"  -c -o plr.o plr.c
In file included from /usr/local/pgsql-9.1/include/server/postgres.h:47,
                 from plr.h:38,
                 from plr.c:33:
/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/include/server/c.h:67:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/include/server/c.h:68:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
...
```

and then pages more of errors.

It seems to me that *make* is looking in the wrong place for the standard header files and can't find them.From my reading around it seems that the flag `-isysroot` is telling *gcc* to look for header files by prepending the normal search path(s) with the `/developer.../macosx10.6.sdk` path and this path does not exist on my machine, which I believe is standard with the current version of Xcode.

So, the question:

Is this flag set somehow by the *Makefile* within /plr, or is it set somewhere else? Either way, how do I change it to get *make* to find the header files that it needs? If changing it is, indeed, the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to bodge a solution to my own question. Maybe someone can help with tidying it up?

`make USE_PGXS=1` formats a series of flags and then calls *gcc* with the flags it's calculated. So, I copied and pasted the line `gcc...` above and then changed the path after `-isysroot` to be one where the standard header files are found. Then the command runs properly, and compiles the file it's been told to.

I had to do this several times, once for each file to be compiled, until a full set exists, and then repeat the exercise using `make install` instead.

After many runs at this, I ended up with the shared object I needed in the right location, and then resumed following the instructions from Joe Conway's wiki.

It works great now. It would be great to know how to stop/change the *-isysroot* setting permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I use MacPorts's postgresql92 +python +perl variant (after earlier compiling PostgreSQL myself) and it has worked flawlessly in each of the recent builds I've done on three computers: http://iangow.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/install-plr-on-os-x-10-8-4-using-macports/ (description of earlier process here: http://iangow.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/plr-on-os-x/).

Comment: Thank you. I will try this sometime, but currently I've got Kyngchaos PostgreSQL, because that is easier with his PostGIS, PGRouting and associated libraries.